# What's wrong with these system calls?

Tags: c, system-calls

**I'm at a loss debugging this code. I copied the example from a guide, is this file being improperly indexed?**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char *inicio(void);

main(void)
{
  char *c;
  int fd, sz, i;    
  c = inicio();

  fd = open("input.in", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) { perror("r1"); exit(1); }

  sz = read(fd, c, 10);
  printf("We have opened input.in, and have called read(%d, c, 10).\n", fd);
  printf("read has read %d bytes.\n", sz);
  printf("The bytes are these: %s\n", c);

  i = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
  printf("lseek(%d, 0, SEEK_CUR) returns the current location on the file being %d\n\n", fd, i);

  printf("We now look for the start of the file and call read(%d, c, 10)\n",fd);
  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  sz = read(fd, c, 10);

  printf("The reading returns the following bytes: %s\n", c);

  printf("We now execute lseek(%d, -6, SEEK_END). and return %d\n",fd, (int) lseek(fd, -6, SEEK_END));
  printf("Executing read(%d, c, 10), we get the following bytes: ", fd);

  sz = read(fd, c, 10);

  printf("Finally, we execute lseek(%d, -1, SEEK_SET).  This returns -1.\n", fd);
  printf("perror() indicates the fault:\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  i = lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET);
  perror("l1");
}

char *inicio(void)
{
  char *bytes;
  int j;
  bytes = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));
  for(j=0;j<100;j++){bytes[j]=rand()%32+1;}
  return bytes;
}
```

the input file is:

```
 Jim Plank
 Claxton 221
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the output produced.  And the input -- does _input.in_ actually contain 16 or so characters?

Comment: Sure, I missed it. Now it's added.

Comment: You ask "what's wrong", without giving us a clue to the symptoms.  What actually is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you seek to a negative offset from the start of the file, you get an error - there are no accessible bytes before the beginning of the file.

Also, you should always check or capture the results of system calls, rather than relying on `errno` being set.  The C library never sets `errno` to zero (other than when the process/thread starts).  It can be set to a non-zero value even if the function succeeded.  On Solaris, it is routine for `errno` to be set after writing to a file because the file is not a terminal and the library attempts an operation that only succeeds on a terminal.

---

Working code, minus memory allocation via 'malloc()'.  It explicitly prints only the number of characters read ('`<<%.*s>>`' limits the length to the size given; the angle brackets make it easy to see the data that is being printed).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c[100];
    int fd, sz, i;

    fd = open("input.in", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
         perror("Error from open(\"input.in\", O_RDONLY)");
         exit(1);
     }

    sz = read(fd, c, 10);
    printf("Opened input.in (fd = %d)\n", fd);
    printf("We called read(fd, c, 10) and read %d bytes: <<%.*s>>\n",
           sz, sz, c);

    i = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) returns the current offset of %d\n", i);

    printf("We seek to start of the file and call read(fd, c, 10)\n");
    i = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (i != 0)
        perror("Error from lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)\n");

    sz = read(fd, c, 10);
    if (sz < 0)
        perror("Error from read(fd, c, 10)\n");
    printf("We read the following bytes: <<%.*s>>\n", sz, c);

    printf("We now execute lseek(fd, -6, SEEK_END) which returns %d\n", 
           (int) lseek(fd, -6, SEEK_END));
    printf("Executing read(fd, c, 10), we get the following bytes: ");

    sz = read(fd, c, 10);
    if (sz < 0)
        perror("Error from read(fd, c, 10)\n");
    printf("<<%.*s>>\n", sz, c);

    printf("Finally, we execute lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET) which returns -1\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    if ((i = lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET)) < 0)
        perror("Error from lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET)");
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Opened input.in (fd = 3)
We called read(fd, c, 10) and read 10 bytes: <<Jim Plank
>>
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) returns the current offset of 10
We seek to start of the file and call read(fd, c, 10)
We read the following bytes: <<Jim Plank
>>
We now execute lseek(fd, -6, SEEK_END) which returns 16
Executing read(fd, c, 10), we get the following bytes: <<n 221
>>
Finally, we execute lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET) which returns -1
Error from lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_SET): Invalid argument
i = -1
```

Comment: I copied this offset from a guide. I changed each negative for a positive and got a Segmentation Fault, what's the proper way to index here?

Comment: @omgzor: I'm not sure what you mean - you can't change the signs on everything and expect it to work.  Seeking 6 beyond the end of a readonly file is not usually going to help very much, for example.  I've updated the answer with non-crashing code.

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding the use of the offset. I changed the last lseek to   i = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) based on your answer and got what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("The bytes are these: %s\n", c);`

Access violation (guaranteed one). You don't have a `'\0'` terminator.

Same goes for:

`printf("The reading returns the following bytes: %s\n", c);`

Comment: Where should the terminator be placed? On the read file? I'm not used to C and its memory errors.

Comment: This is a valid problem with the code - it is not an explanation for why the last `lseek()` fails.

Comment: @Jonathan Cause it can never be reached?

Comment: @omgzor First, don't initialize the array with values 1..32 but zeroes (using `memset()`) and when you are done reading reset the whole array back to zero (using `memset()`).

Comment: I added c[sz] = '\0'; after each read call and got the same error :/

Comment: I'm not convinced; have you tried it?  There's likely to be a zero byte in range before too much reading out of bounds occurs.  Not guaranteed - but likely.  Granted, the printed data is a mess; that is not in dispute (nor am I disputing that it is a genuine problem that you've identified).  But, there is nothing here that explains why the last `lseek()` is returning an error.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a C n00b here. How should the call to memset be specified?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: C++ reference for a C function that should probably rarely/never be used in C++? How about this instead: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html

Comment: @R Yes I rather post a C++ reference material, that includes examples than a link to man.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you expect at the -1th position of the file? Maybe you wanted SEEK_CUR or SEEK_END instead of SEEK_SET.

Answer (score -1):

```
c[sz] = '\0';
```

after the read calls.